# Read Brodcast (ff02::1) msg python socket

Tags: python, sockets, broadcastreceiver, ipv6

i have this code to read a msg from a client.

```
import socket

# UDP_IP = 'fd53:7cb8:383:2::10'
UDP_IP = '::'
UDP_PORT = 13400
# create socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

# bind the socket
server_add = (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)
print('starting up on {} on port {}'.format(*server_add))
sock.bind(server_add)
while True:
    print('waiting msg')
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print("received message:", data)
    print("addr is", addr)
    sock.close()
    break

the client IP is : 'fd53:7cb8:383:2::c9'
the Server IP is : 'fd53:7cb8:383:2::10'
```

i can saw the msg on wireshark

| No. | Time | Delta | Source | Destination | Protocol | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 6.516768 | 3.631930 | fd53:7cb8:383:2::c9 | ff02::1 | DoIP | 103 |

but the `sock.recvfrom(1024)` is not getting anything

Comment: `SO_BROADCAST` is for sending broadcasts, not receiving them.

Comment: IPv6 does not have broadcast. Instead, it uses multicast, and addresses in the `ff00::/8` range are multicast addresses, not broadcast addresses.

Comment: ff02::1 is a "well-known" multicast address Link Local All Nodes,

Comment: Yes, but it is a multicast address, _not_ a broadcast address. IPv6 does not have broadcast. IPv4 also has the `224.0.0.1` All Nodes multicast address, but neither is that a broadcast address. There is a difference between broadcast and multicast.

Comment: Should I remove the line "sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)" and should work?